# Azure Cognitive Services - Timeout limitation

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

We have implemented Azure Cognitive Services (Text Translation API) in our CRM solution and it's working fine. But sometimes it's giving an error as **The request was aborted: The operation has timed out**. But I could not find any information related to this API time limitations. It would be helpful, if any one can share information on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See reference [here](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1147546-api-translator-text-limits):

> Latency: **13 seconds**. Microsoft Translator has a maximum latency of 13
>   seconds. At that time you will have received the result or a timeout
>   response. The typical response time for a short request is 150 to 300
>   milliseconds. The typical response time varies per request size and
>   per language pair.